# Partial JSON serialisation/de-serialization using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a problem that I cannot resolve for a while.
Lets imagine a very simple Java class

```
class Foo {
     public String bar;
     public String baz;
}
```

How can I accomplish that the operation of deserialisation and consequent serialisation of some JSON request is actually immutable in terms of partial JSON objects. So that if I unserialise

```
{
    "bar": "some value",
    "baz": null
}
```

into Foo instance and then serialise it back to JSON, I get

```
{
    "bar": "some value",
    "baz": null
}
```

and if I unserialize partial JSON without "baz"

```
{
    "bar": "some value"
}
```

I get again a partial JSON without "baz"

```
{
    "bar": "some value"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible unless you store information about which fields were present in the original JSON objects. For this purpose, you could use a wrapper around `Foo` which contains a `Foo` plus this addtional info. Below is an example.

Note: this is **pseudocode**. The method and class names are part from the Gson library and part invented by me on the fly, but you get the idea. I think it shouldn't be difficult to translate this using the classes of Jackson.

```
class DeserializedFoo {

    private Foo foo;
    private Set<String> includedFields = new HashSet<>();

    private DeserializedFoo(){

    }

    public static class DeSerializer implements JsonDeserializer<DeserializedFoo> {
        @Override
        public DeserializedFoo deserialize(JsonElement je) {
            DeserializedFoo dsFoo = new DeserializedFoo();
            dsFoo.foo = parse(je);
            for(JsonElement prop : je.elements()){
                includedFields.add(prop.getName());
            }
            return dsFoo;
        }
    }

    public static class Serializer implements JsonSerializer<DeserializedFoo> {
        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(DeserializedFoo dsFoo) {
            JsonElement jsonFoo = serialize(dsFoo.foo);

            // Leave only fields that were present in the JSON 
            // element from which this was deserialized.
            Iterable it = jsonFoo.elements().iterable();
            while(it.hasNext()){
                JsonElement prop = it.next();
                if(!includedFields.contains(prop.getName()){
                    it.remove();
                }
            }
            return jsonFoo;
        }
    }   
}
```

You could of course use inheritance instead of a wrapper, e.g. by defining `class DeserilizedFoo extends Foo` and adding the `includedFields` field. Each approach has its benefits and drawbacks. It's up to you to decide which one fits your situation best.

Answer (score 1):

You can annotated your class with [@JsonInclude(Include.NON_DEFAULT)](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_DEFAULT) and 
set the default value for `baz` property to a magic string which would indicate that the value should not be present in the JSON.

Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonIncludeNull {

    final static String JSON1 = "{\n" +
            "    \"bar\": \"some value\",\n" +
            "    \"baz\": null\n" +
            "}";

    final static String JSON2 = "{\n" +
            "    \"bar\": \"some value\"\n" +
            "}";

    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_DEFAULT)
    static class Foo {
        public String bar;
        public String baz = "##default";

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo{" +
                    "bar='" + bar + '\'' +
                    ", baz='" + baz + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new GuavaModule());
        final Foo foo1 = mapper.readValue(JSON1, Foo.class);
        System.out.println(JSON1);
        System.out.println("Object: " + foo1);
        System.out.println("Serialize: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(foo1));

        System.out.println();

        final Foo foo2 = mapper.readValue(JSON2, Foo.class);
        System.out.println(JSON2);
        System.out.println("Object: " + foo2);
        System.out.println("Serialize: " + mapper.writeValueAsString(foo2));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "bar": "some value",
    "baz": null
}
Object: Foo{bar='some value', baz='null'}
Serialize: {"bar":"some value","baz":null}

{
    "bar": "some value"
}
Object: Foo{bar='some value', baz='##default'}
Serialize: {"bar":"some value"}
```